# getting error when i deploy the NFT with ETH

Tags: ethereum, solidity, nft, hardhat, openzeppelin

I am new in NFT, i am trying to create test NFT, when i am trying to deploy that NFT, i am getting this error,`insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction cost`, even though in my account have 1 ETH balance  here i have attached my whole code of it, can anyone please help me, how to resolve this issue ?
MyNFT.sol

```
//Contract based on [https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/erc721](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/erc721)
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";

contract MyNFT is ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {   
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

    constructor() ERC721("MyNFT", "NFT") {}

    function mintNFT(address recipient, string memory tokenURI)
        public onlyOwner
        returns (uint256)
    {
        _tokenIds.increment();

        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(recipient, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);

        return newItemId;
    }
}
```

hardhat.config.js

```
/**

* @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig

*/

require('dotenv').config();
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
const { API_URL, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;
//console.log(PRIVATE_KEY);
module.exports = {
   solidity: "0.8.1",
   defaultNetwork: "ropsten",
   networks: {
      hardhat: {},
      ropsten: {
         url: API_URL,
         accounts: [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`]
      }
   },
}
```

deploy.js

```
async function main() {
    const MyNFT = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyNFT")
  
    // Start deployment, returning a promise that resolves to a contract object
    const myNFT = await MyNFT.deploy()
    await myNFT.deployed()      
    console.log("Contract deployed to address:", myNFT.address)
  }
  
  main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error)
      process.exit(1)
    })
```

Comment: This snippet is trying to deploy the contract to Ropsten testnet. Balance on one network does not affect balance on another. Can you confirm that you have the 1 ETH on the deployer address on Ropsten?

Comment: yes i have 4ETH alance

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is clear. you do not have sufficient funds. This is how you are getting the account information:

```
const { API_URL, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;
```

I had an issue with webpack once destructuring `process.env`. Try this

```
// ASSUMING you pass correct private key here
const PRIVATE_KEY  = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;
```

console.log the private key.

If it does not get resolved, that means you are not passing the correct PRIVATE_KEY.

Comment: I tried this and the correct private key gets printed to the console.  Can you offer any other insight?